# Há diferença entre núcleo e CPU? Se sim, qual(is)?

Tags: terminologia

As configurações de um computador diz que há dois núcleos e três processadores, e pensava que eram termos sinônimos, mas pelo que indica não. Podendo explicar de forma breve as suas diferenças, agradeço

Comment: Depende do contexto. Provavelmente são truques de linguagem para parecer melhor do que é. De qualquer forma não é sobre programação.

Comment: @bigown É porque eu sempre entendi que ambas palavras fossem sinônimas. Mas após isso fiquei em dúvida. Ter 3 processadores faz sentido, pois é um i3, mas dois núcleos? Fiquei com essa dúvida.

Comment: @JNMarcos Intel i3 é apenas um indicativo da geração de processadores (3º). você pode ver a especificação do entry model i3 neste link: http://ark.intel.com/products/71053/Intel-Core-i3-3210-Processor-3M-Cache-3_20-GHz

Comment: @Ibotinelly, tem certeza? Porque no mesmo site encontrei o i7 (que seguindo o que entendi o que você disse, seria a sétima geração), mas o i7 teve/tem ... 3ª, 4ª, 5ª, 6ª geração

Comment: i3, i5 e i7 são apenas a maneira marqueteira com que a Intel nomeou os produtos da sua linha de processadores, sendo o i3 o menos poderoso e mais barato, e o i7 o mais poderoso e mais caro. Os números não têm relação com a quantidade de núcleos, e toda a família já passou por várias gerações.

Comment: JNMarcos não, não tenho. O @bfavaretto está certo, eu entendi incorretamente uma fonte que consultei para lhe responder.

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma resposta muito boa no Stack Overflow em inglês. Abaixo a tradução:

> Um núcleo é geralmente a unidade de computação básica da CPU, podendo executar um único contexto de programa (ou vários se ele suportar threads de hardware, como no caso de hyperthreading nos processadores da Intel), mantendo o estado corre to do programa, registradores, e a correta ordem de execução, e executar as operações através de ALUs (*arithmetic logic unit*, ou unidade de lógica aritmética). Para fins de otimização, um núcleo também pode manter caches internos com cópias de pedaços de memória usados ​​com freqüência.
>
> Uma CPU pode ter um ou mais núcleos para executar tarefas em um determinado momento. Essas tarefas são geralmente processos de software e e threads que o ambiente operacional agenda. Perceba que o sistema operacional pode ter muitas threads para executar, mas a CPU só pode executar, em um determinado momento, X tais tarefas - onde X = número de núcleos * número de threads de hardware por núcleo. O resto teria que esperar pelo sistema operacional para sofrer agendamento.
>
> Em adição a um ou vários núcleos, a CPU também irá possuir alguma ligação entre os núcleos e o mundo exterior, geralmente geralmente na forma de um cache compartilhado. Existem vários outros elementos-chave necessários para fazer uma CPU funcionar, mas estas podem variar de acordo com o design. Você vai precisar de um controlador de memória para falar com a memória, controladores IO (visualização, PCIe, USB, etc ..). No passado, estes elementos estavam fora da CPU, no "chipset" complementar, mas o design mais moderno os têm integrados na CPU.

Fonte: ['Difference between core and processor?', Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19314303/1845714)